# Is it possible to use just a transistor as an RF amplifier?

Tags: rf

Is it possible to use a transistor (such as the B1342 transistor) as an RF amplifier, no resistors, and no capacitors?

I'm trying to amplify the output signal from this schematic, and I don't have many parts:

[image]

Comment: No, the resistors especially are absolutely 100% required.

Comment: That's kind of like asking "Can I drive this car without a steering wheel or wheels?"  The engine is still there, but you won't get far.  There are self-contained RF amplifiers that don't require much in the way of external components, but they're not single transistors.

Comment: Alright, thank you. Obviously I'm just beginning this stuff, so I also want to thank you for understanding.